# How to conclude significance testing with random sampling?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, p-value

I am new to statistics, and I'm doing significance testing. I just need some guidance and clarity.
Suppose I have this data: [image]

It has 240000 total records of salaries from year 2005 and 2006. The task is to get random 15% of samples per year and test whether the increase in salary from 2005 to 2006 can be considered significant. I understand that this can be done by using t-test and computing for the p-value then concluding whether the null hypothesis should be rejected. However, I'm getting different p-values each time I try to test, and I believe this is because of the random 15% sampling.

How do I go about/conclude this? I'm not sure if I'm in the right direction

Comment: According to the definition of p-value, when in fact there is no difference in mean salaries then you should expect the p-values in your tests to vary randomly and nearly uniformly between $0$ and $1.$  When there is an increase in salary, the p-values will concentrate near $0$ but they will still vary randomly.  You can see this in many simulations posted here on CV.  Visit some of the top hits at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=p+value+simulation, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are likely (extremely likely) to get slightly different results each time, just due to random sampling. It sounds like you’re doing it right. Just use a seed (e.g. set.seed in R or np.random.seed in Python) in your work so others can reproduce your results. That makes it so you get the same random sample each time you run your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I really appreciate it. But what if, sometimes I'm getting p-values of < 0.05 and another minute I test, I get a p-value of >0.05 (like 90% of the time it is > 0.05 and 10% of the time it's the opposite.) Does that mean that one can reject the null hypothesis because of luck?

Comment: Here’s a suggestion. Do 1000 or 10,000 samples (using code, perhaps some kind of loop), and graph a histogram of the t-test p-values. Post that image in your original question, and we’ll talk. Comment back here when you’ve posted that. Briefly, you do expect a certain number of type II errors (incorrectly missing a true difference) when the null is false. Likewise, when the null is true, you expect a certain number ($\alpha$) of type I errors (rejecting even though the null is true).

Comment: Hi Dave, I posted a question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493465/how-to-conclude-significance-testing-with-random-sampling 

based on this comment. Would love to hear from you in there if possible. I posted a separate question as I don't want to extend this comment section unnecessarily.

Comment: That links back to this question.

Comment: Sorry, does this link work? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493495/using-repeat-measurements-to-increase-validity