# Using repeat measurements to increase validity?

Tags: cross-validation, p-value, model

[User Dave posted an answer to a relatively simple question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493465/how-to-conclude-significance-testing-with-random-sampling), but with an interesting twist in the comments. Here, the idea seems to be to run repeat measurements on random samples, drafting a histogram based on p-values obtained.

I'm wondering if this is the same as k-folding, or if it's a different approach? I'm looking for a general explanation of the application and reasoning for using this method, and does it increase the validity of a study? If not, what boons does it achieve as compared to simply running one regression/hypothesis test on the dataset and obtaining one p-value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task behind the question to which you link, for some unspecified reason, *requires* repeated subsampling of a random 15% of a data sample. That's throwing away 85% of the data each time. In general, throwing away data isn't a good idea. If you have 240,000 data points, why not just use them all at once?

The procedure is *not* $k$-fold cross-validation. That means breaking apart the *total data sample* into $k$ non-overlapping subsets, building $k$ models on data from which one subset is held out, evaluating the model on the held-out subset, and combining the evaluations over all $k$ models to get an estimate of modeling performance. Nor is it bootstrapping, in which you generally take random samples with replacement *of the same size as the original sample* to try to evaluate the distribution of a statistic in the underlying population. In the linked question, there is no obvious purpose to the repeated 15% sub-sampling except to get a large set of p-values based on less-than-complete data.

My sense is that the basis for both the original task and Dave's  suggestion is pedagogical. The idea is presumably to treat the 240,000 data points as a complete population, with each 15% representing a sample from the population. If the null hypothesis holds, then among the multiple samples there should be a *uniform distribution* of p-values over [0,1]. If the null hypothesis does not hold, then the p-values will be more concentrated toward 0. Examining the distribution of p-values in the latter case will illustrate the power of the test (the fraction of samples in which the p-values are less than the threshold for "significance). Simply repeating the same analysis on multiple subsets of a large data set, as in the question to which you link, doesn't help the statistical analysis except for that pedagogical purpose.

Comment: Thank you EDM. In essence, is it safe to say that Dave's answer is more leaning towards explaining p-values?

Comment: @Paze that's the simplest way to put it. I think that the potential connection to also exploring power goes beyond just "explaining p-values," though.

Comment: That's true, thank you for clarifying this! The first paragraph is also something to think about as a non-statistician.